# Excel Interop "New Up" objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel, interop

I'm working on an MVC application where users can upload an excel document and output HTML but I'm having some difficulty with the Interop libraries and I hope someone can help.

To keep this really simple, I have reached a stage where I want to instantiate or "new up" a worksheet and use the id of the chosen sheet. The user has selected the sheet they wish to use but there doesn't seem to be any method of doing this.

I have tried code such as `workbookModel.workbook.Sheets.get_Item(1);` which should get the current workbook in the model and get the sheet with id 1 - I believe this is 1 based index as opposed to 0-based. Bear in mind I have some viewModels in play hence above code, but all I'm really doing here is `Workbook work = new Workbook().Sheets.get_Item(1);`

I have also tried `Workbook work = new Workbook().Worksheets.get_Item(1);` in case I was incorrectly using Worksheets instead of sheets but I don't believe so.

But nothing I've tried seems to work.

If anyone can point me in the right direction that will be much appreciated and if this hasn't made sense and you need more info please let me know.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you using [Gembox](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/overview) to do this or just interop?

Comment: Just Interop - I'll take a look at Gembox though

Comment: The `Application` contains `Workbooks` - Workbooks are Excel Files.
`Workbook` contains `Worksheets` - Worksheets are Tabs or Sheets in the file. Indexes in Excel Interop are 1-based. But you can get them by `names` as well: `(Worksheet)Workbook.Worksheets("SheetName");`

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do, but I'm experienced with excel interop, so if you could translate more clearly what that `new up` means....

Comment: @Daniel thanks yes you are correct and I was also correct with that. I used id in the example but I have actually been working with names but that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Basically put, the user uploads the spreadsheet and is taken to a view containing the available sheets in the workbook. Each of these is an ActionLink which takes them to a view containing the available html templates.

At this point I'd like to perform some actions such as pulling the data from the chosen sheet, however at this point all I have is a string containing the template name and a string containing the Worksheet name so I would like to New Up a Worksheet and set the name or id of it to be the selected worksheet so I can then start to work with the data in it

Comment: Seems like you're trying to assign a `worksheet` to a variable declared as `workbook`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, Interop only works if you have an excel application running.

So, if you don't have it running, you will need to:

```
Application ExcelApp = new Application();
```

To get a worksheet from the application, you will need the workbook first. 
You can get the workbook with one of the following:

```
//to get the first workbook of an application
Workbook MyBook = ExcelApp.Workbooks[1];

//to get a workbook by name
Workbook MyBook = ExcelApp.Workbooks["bookname"];

//to open a workbook from a xls file
Workbook MyBook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(name and other parameters);

//to add a new workbook to the application
Workbook MyBook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Add(optional template);
```

Note that a workbook cannot exist without the running application, nor a sheet can exist without a parent workbook in a running application

To get a worksheet from a workbook, you will need to cast it, because it comes `as object`.

```
//to get an existing sheet
Worksheet MySheet = (Worksheet)MyBook.Worksheets["sheetname"];

//to create a new sheet
Worksheet MySheet = (Worksheet)MyBook.Worksheets.Add(some parameters);
```

But if you could manage to get the names from the sheets to populate the view with links, you could store those sheet instances and pass them to the method that creates the html.
Or store them in global variables.

Comment: Hey Daniel
Thanks for sending this.
I probably should have explained better - I have created an Application object and the rest so I have done pretty much everything you suggest...

But your comment has left me with one realisation, which is that by the time I come to this method, the Application object has been closed and therefore I won't be able to access the Worksheets.

I will try to New Up another Application object and see if I can get at the Worksheets like my previous code.

Thanks for the suggestion. I will respond on here to let you know.

Comment: You could keep the application open as well (and the workbook), that would make things faster.

Comment: That's actually much easier because otherwise it would be a hack to get the filename again, since it's coming from an upload!

What is the difference between Workbook.ActiveWorkbook and Workbook.ThisWorkbook ? Which should I use to call the current open book?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm making this more difficult than it needs to be but does the application object remain open across page requests? I think when I route to another view that object is closed, meaning I'm back to my original problem of getting the filename when it's coming from an upload.

I may have to store the file name in tempdata unless you know of a way to keep this object alive?

Comment: First, the `ActiveWorkbook` and `ThisWorkbook` exist in the `Application` object, not in the `Workbook` object. (An application may contain many workbooks).
Since the application can have many workbooks, the `ActiveWorkbook` is the one that the user is looking at, the selected one, the active. 
The `ThisWorkbook` is used only in VBA. When you create a VBA code, you can put it in modules or inside a workbook. It returns the Workbook where code is writen. (Won't work in Interop since your code exists completely independand from the application).

Comment: If you create the application and you're sure there's only one workbook, you can use the `ActiveWorkbook`, but if you can have more than one, I'd get them by names, because it's a lot safer.

Comment: I can't tell about page requests. I'm a total newbie with web applications.

Comment: Ok as I suspected then it must be ActiveWorkbook since I'm definitely not using VBA!

I think I'll have to go with TempData which is like a session object because there could be many users uploading at once and I don't want to get into a mess.

Again, I'll post the solution when I have one but thanks for your ongoing assistance :D

Comment: Hi Daniel - Storing the name in TempData and Newing Up an Application object has done the trick! So thanks very much for your help on that!!

Now I just need to figure out how to output the html using a template and I'm done :)